# How to get the selected radio button value using js

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am using this code to get the value of currently selected radio button, but it doesn't work.

```
var mailcopy = document.getElementById('mailCopy').value;
```

How to get the currently selected radio button value using Javascript?

Answer (score 91):

HTML

```
<p>Gender</p>
<input type="radio" id="gender0" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" id="gender1" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br>
```

JS

```
var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked').value;
document.writeln("You entered " + gender + " for your gender<br>");
```

Comment: Lovely. And no need for a parent element.

Answer (score 48):

If you are using jQuery, following code will work for you.

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 34):

Radio buttons come in groups which have the same name and different ids, one of them will have the checked property set to true, so loop over them until you find it.

```
function getCheckedRadio(radio_group) {
    for (var i = 0; i < radio_group.length; i++) {
        var button = radio_group[i];
        if (button.checked) {
            return button;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
var checkedButton = getCheckedRadio(document.forms.frmId.elements.groupName);
if (checkedButton) {
    alert("The value is " + checkedButton.value);
}
```

Comment: Good for compatibility, this method works for older browsers too, pre HTML 5.

Answer (score 4):

check this

```
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".gender").change(function () {

    var val = $('.gender:checked').val();
    alert(val);
});
});

</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaymv/da8P2/)

Comment: my requirement is quite different, the alert box will come but at the click on the button

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but wouldn't the good old standard JS work? I mean:

```
var selectedOption = document.getElementById('your-form-name')['radio-group-name'].value;
```

... which is only valid of course if have provided "value" for your radio input elements.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-group-name" value="red" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group-name" value="blue">
```

The value should be either 'red' or 'blue' in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getCheckedValue(radioObj, name) {

    for (j = 0; j < radioObj.rows.length; ++j) {
        for (k = 0; k < radioObj.cells.length; ++k) {
            var radioChoice = document.getElementById(name + "_" + k);
            if (radioChoice.checked) {
                return radioChoice.value;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of doing this is to use a global js variable that simply holds the id of the clicked radio button. Then you don't have to waste code spinning thru your radio lists looking for the selected value. 
I have done this in cases where I have a dynamically generated list of 100 or more radio buttons. spinning thru them is (almost imperceptible) slow, but this is an easier solution.

you can also do this with the id, but you usually just want the value.

```
<script>
var gRadioValue = ''; //global declared outside of function
function myRadioFunc(){
    var radioVal = gRadioValue;  
    // or maybe: var whichRadio = document.getElementById(gWhichCheckedId);
    //do somethign with radioVal
}
<script>

<input type="radio" name="rdo" id="rdo1" value="1" onClick="gRadioValue =this.value;"> One
<input type="radio" name="rdo" id="rdo2" value="2" onClick="gRadioValue =this.value;"> Two
...
<input type="radio" name="rdo" id="rdo99" value="99" onClick="gRadioValue =this.value;"> 99
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$('input[name="field_value"]:checked').val();
```

or, for older version of jquery

```
$('input[@name="field_value"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get it using plain javascript, you can use the following code

```
var val = '';
if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked) {
  val = document.getElementById('radio1').value
}else if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked) {
  val = document.getElementById('radio2').value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the most efficient way... but I have used an ID on each radio button (this is just because I'm not passing it as an actual form, it is just the raw fields).

I then call a function with a button, which checks each radio button to see if it is checked. It does this using the `.checked` function. If this is set to true I can change the value of another variable.

```js
function createOutput() {
  var order = "in";
  if (document.getElementById('radio1').checked == true) {
    order = "pre";
  } else if (document.getElementById('radio2').checked == true) {
    order = "in";
  } else if (document.getElementById('radio3').checked == true) {
    order = "post";
  }
  document.getElementById('outputBox').innerHTML = order;
}
```

```html
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="order" value="preorder" />Preorder
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="order" value="inorder" checked="true" />Inorder
<input id="radio3" type="radio" name="order" value="postorder" />Postorder
<button onclick="createOutput();">Generate Output</button>
<textarea id="outputBox" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Hope this is useful, in someway,

Beanz

Answer (score 0):

You could do something very similar to Beanz's answer but instead of using IDs, use classes to reduce redundancy.

```js
function getSelectedValue() {
  var radioBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("radioBtn");
  for(var i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++){
    if(radioBtns[i].checked){
      document.getElementById("output").textContent = radioBtns[i].value; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" value="button1" />Button 1<br>
<input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" value="button2" />Button 2<br>
<input class="radioBtn" type="radio" name="order" value="button3" />Button 3<br>
<button onclick="getSelectedValue();">Get Value of Selected Radio</button><br>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

all of you can test this example and easy to understand.

```
        Name:   <input type="text" id="text" class ="input">
                <input type="text" id="text1" class ="input">
        Gender: <input type="radio" id="m" class="Rm"  name="Rmale" value="Male">
                <input type="radio" id="f" class="Rm" name="Rfemale" value="Female">
        Course: <input type="checkbox" id="math" class="cm" name="Cmath" value="Math">
                <input type="checkbox" id="physic" class="cm" name="Cphysic" value="Physic">
                <input type="checkbox" id="eng" class="cm"  name="Ceng" value="English">
        <button type="button" id="b1">show</button>
```

// javascript

```
    <script>
        function getData(input){
            return document.getElementById(input).value;
        }
        function dataByClassName(st){
            var value=document.getElementsByClassName(st)
            for(var i=0;i < value.length;i++){
                if(value[i].checked){
                    return value[i].value;
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("b1").onclick = function ()
        {
            var st={
                name : getData("text")+getData("text1"),
                gender : dataByClassName("Rm"),
                course : dataByClassName("cm")
            };
            alert(st.name+" "+st.gender+" "+st.course);
        };

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this one will work

```
function loadRadioButton(objectName, selectedValue) {

    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName(objectName);

    if (radioButtons != null) {
        for (var radioCount = 0; radioCount < radioButtons.length; radioCount++) {
            if (radioButtons[radioCount].value == selectedValue) {
                radioButtons[radioCount].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can use jQuery "Chamika Sandamal" answer is the correct way to go. In the case you can't use jQuery you can do something like this:

```
function selectedRadio() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('mailCopy');
    alert(radio[0].value);
}
```

**Notes:**

- In general for the inputs you want to have unique IDs (not a requirement but a good practice)
- All the radio inputs that are from the same group MUST have the same name attribute, for example
- You have to set the value attribute for each input

Here is an example of input radios:

```
<input type="radio" name="mailCopy" value="1" />1<br />
<input type="radio" name="mailCopy" value="2" />2<br />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
document.querySelector('#elementId:checked').value;
```

This will return the value of the selected radio button.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
this.template.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var mailcopy = document.getElementById('mailCopy').checked; 

if(mailcopy==true)
{
  alert("Radio Button Checked");
}
else
{
  alert("Radio Button un-Checked");
}
```

Comment: The question is looking to get the currently selected button, not find out if a specific button is checked.

Answer (score -2):

Hy, you have to do it this way.

```
function checkRadio () {
    if(document.getElementById('user1').checked) {
        return $('#user1').val();
    }else if(document.getElementById('user2').checked) {
        return $('#user2').val();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the `element.checked` property.