# Check for value type in a radio input

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button

I was wondering how you check for a value in a radio input, Iḿ having trouble with the syntax, Iḿ not quite sure whether I should put quotation marks or not, I've tried to test them out but when I click the Enter button it says my file cannot be found so I can´t test it out. But I just need help with how to check for a value in a radio input, if you can help me figure out the proper syntax i´d really appreciate it!

Hereś what Iḿ trying to do:

The user inputs some text > the text has the id = "name1"
The user selects one of the following options > yes; kind of; no
The user clicks enter button > the function organizeUnderstanding1() is suppose to organize the input name1 into either result1H; result1M; result1E; depending on what they selected with the radio inputs

```
       <div>
        <input type="text" id="name1">
    </div>

 <div id="understandingCheck1">
      <form>
        <p>Question 1?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="yes1" name="understanding1" value="yes" required>
        <label for="yes">yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="kindOf1" name="understanding1" value="kindOf">
        <label for="kinda">kind of</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="no1" name="understanding1" value="no">
        <label for="no">no</label><br><br>
        <button onclick="hideUnderstandingCheckDiv(); organizeUnderstanding1();">Enter</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    
      <div id="workDiv">
        <p>Here´s what you said YES to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1H"></span></p>
        <p>Here's what you said KIND OF to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1K"></p>  
        <p>Hereś what you said NO to:</p>
        <p><span id="result1Y"></span></p>
      </div>
    
    
      <script>
      
      function hideUnderstandingCheckDiv(){              
          
          document.getElementById("understandingCheck1").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("workDiv").style.display = "block";
          
      }
      
      
      function organizeUnderstanding1() {
      var understanding1 = document.getElementByName("understanding1").required;
              if (understanding1.value =="yes" ){
                 document.getElementById("result1Y").innerHTML =                        document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else if (understanding1.value =="kinda" ){
                document.getElementById("result1K").innerHTML =                         document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else if (understanding1.value =="no" ){
                document.getElementById("result1N").innerHTML =                         document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else {
                break;
              }
       }
       
    
      </script>
```

Comment: here is a W3schools TryIt Editor of my code: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the selected radio button value using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869535/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-value-using-js)

Comment: `var understanding1 = document.getElementByName("understanding1").required;` is incorrect. There is `document.getElementsByName` but that would give you a live collection, which is an Array-like Object. Then you would have to loop over that. I would actually use `.querySelectorAll` myself. The live collection could be an issue down the road.

Comment: Alright thank you! Iḿ still having trouble with this I made some changes with my code

Comment: @Chris G I don´t know what to do now, but Iḿ having toruble with checking the value here : if (understanding1.value == yes ){
                 document.getElementById("result1Y").innerHTML =                        document.getElementById('name1').value;
              } else if